# How to use plugin translation along with application own translation?

Tags: python, plugins, internationalization, gettext

```
|-- locale
|   `-- es
|       `-- LC_MESSAGES
|           |-- pluginloader.mo
|           `-- pluginloader.po
|-- pluginloader.py
`-- plugins
    `-- PluginA
        |-- first_plugin
        |   `-- __init__.py
        |-- manifest.json
        `-- po
            |-- es.po
            `-- first_plugin.pot
```

I have above structure for my app(pluginloader) which uses it's own tranlation from locale directory. I would like to use pluginA translation es.po in pluginA. How i can do that? I am importing plugins in pluginloader by following code. 
`

```
import imp
import os
import gettext

t = gettext.translation('pluginloader', localedir='locale', languages=['es'], fallback=True)
t.install()

PluginFolder = "./plugins"
MainModule = "__init__"

print(_("Hello world"))

def getPlugins():
    plugins = []
    possibleplugins = os.listdir(PluginFolder)
    for i in possibleplugins:
        location = os.path.join(PluginFolder, i)
        for j in os.listdir(location):
            location1 = os.path.join(location, j)
            if not os.path.isdir(location1) or not MainModule + ".py" in os.listdir(location1):
                continue
            info = imp.find_module(MainModule, [location1])
            plugins.append({"name": i, "info": info})
    return plugins

def loadPlugin(plugin):
    return imp.load_module(MainModule, *plugin["info"])

for i in getPlugins():
    plugin = loadPlugin(i)
    plugin.run()`
```

Comment: Between i know i should use import lib as imp has been deprecated. :-)

Comment: I think you title should be a bit more descriptive of your problem if you want to get answers.

Comment: @JosephBudin . Ok..Is it okay now?

Comment: Not really, the title should give information about the problem you want to solve. When I read it, i think "What the hell is 'pluginA' and what is 'this case' ?" I think most people don't even read you question because the title is unclear.

Comment: (Proof: your question was accessed only 5 times)

Comment: @JosephBudin Can you suggest some catching title?